# Issue in creating Selenium remote driver while invoking testcases through Jenkins always encounter urllib.error. [Errno 111] Connection refused>

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am running my pytest cases from Jenkins with two remote machines hosting selenium nodes.

I am able to register remote driver for Machine 1(IP1) over the url http://IP1:5555/wd/hub and get my associated tests done perfectly.

However, sequentially in other test, I am registering remote driver for Machine 2(IP2) using url http://IP2:5555/wd/hub. But I am getting:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

To troubleshoot:

1. I executed from my m/c instead of jenkins environment. Every thing works ok.
2. If I go headless in Jenkins environment, the issue is not reproduced, however I do not want headless due to certain requirements.

I using Chrome browser/chromedriver only and python3.

This issue is always reproducible.

Comment: can your hub see both nodes?

Comment: Yes, the hub can see both nodes.